# Natural language processing / commands (prolog)

Tags: command, prolog, nlp

I want to create a predicate, which recognizes a word (in this case: "save") and starts saving the next words, until the sign/word "end" comes.

It should work like this:

```
?- save.
one
two
end
true.
```

The predicate for saving:

```
save(X) :- assert(listitem(X)).
```

and then I started like this:

```
save :- read(save).
read:- X -> save(X).
end --> 'end'.
```

The problem is, that I can add as much words as I want, but if I want to stop the command with "end", the program fails and actually the words have not been saved.

What part of the predicate is wrong? I'd be very happy for some help.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What will you do if you want to enter the word "end"? How are you going to tell it apart from the end "end"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is some extremely confused code. Here's what you wanted:

```
:- dynamic listitem/1.

readline(Line) :-
  % this is an SWI extension, but it's very handy
  read_line_to_codes(user, Codes),
  atom_codes(Line, Codes).

save :- 
  readline(X), 
  (X \= end -> (assertz(listitem(X)), save)
             ;  true).
```

Odds are good, somewhere in the code you didn't bring, all you were missing was the effect of the `; true` there: that when you find `end`, you're finished, but not that you failed. But you have a lot of problems here.

1. `save/0` calls `read/1`, which is a system predicate. All this is going to do is read a word from the user (ending with a period!) and notice that it isn't the word "save". Unfortunately, reading a whole line without periods at the end is a somewhat non-trivial task in Prolog, hence the pile of code in my solution.
2. `read/0` is not called by anything.
3. The syntax `X -> save(X)` is almost certainly not what you want. This is the first occurrence of `X` in the predicate, and so it probably isn't doing you much good to test it conditionally before it has a value.
4. `end --> 'end'.` is a DCG rule, but you aren't using `phrase/2` anywhere to invoke it (nor are you using `end/2` directly with a difference list).
5. `assert/1` is a really bad habit to get into. The ISO predicates `asserta/1` and `assertz/1` are not only portable, they also give the reader a better idea what the effect on the fact database will be.
6. Similarly, you have no `dynamic` declaration for `listitem/1`, which would raise portability and improve readability.

Comment: A good answer (+1), but I have the feeling that it be cleaner with the `read` family of predicates, without the need for `read_line_to_codes` and `atom_codes`.

Comment: Won't the user need to end lines with periods then? That would change the requirements.

Comment: Yes, but I really doubt those are set in stone.... Something like answer of @CapelliC

Comment: @Boris yes, but even in CapelliC's answer there are periods to end the term. I think you'd have to go with one of the get_(byte,char,code) and a loop to avoid periods, and that's more work (if you know you're using SWI).

Answer (score 1):

I would use a 'state machine' approach: it's so simple!

```
:- dynamic listitem/1.

loop(Mode) :- read(W), loop(Mode, W).

loop(_, stop).
loop(skip, save) :- loop(save).
loop(skip, _) :- loop(skip).
loop(save, W) :- assertz(listitem(W)), loop(save).
```

test:

```
1 ?- loop(skip).
|: asd.
|: save.
|: ok.
|: ok1.
|: stop.
true 
.

2 ?- listing(listitem).
:- dynamic stackoverflow:listitem/1.

stackoverflow:listitem(ok).
stackoverflow:listitem(ok1).

true.
```